Why is berryBoot not working on my RaspberryPi zero 2w?
I have a raspberry pi zero 2W and I used PINN on it but PINN has too many problems, so I want to use BerryBoot instead. If I install the zip with the imager it does not work. I have a 128gb micro sd card and I even made the volume on the card to 32gb so i can make it fat32 but it does not work. The led on the raspberry pi goes on and with any version of BerryBoot the rainbow screen appears but nothing is happening.
How do i get it to work?
PS: If my English is not good it's because i speak german.

AFAICT Berryboot isn't being maintained (last update nearly 3 years ago, as are the last real questions here about it).  Is it even available through the imager or did you download it from somewhere?

i downloaded it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/berryboot/ an when i tried it with the imager i use the custem image file optione

I last used BerryBoot 7 years ago but from what I remember it was very restrictive (all OS had to share a common kernel). Even Raspberry Pi OS has multiple kernels selected on boot. You are probably wasting your time with it.

Use a tool like SD Card Formatter to format your SD card. It should be formatted to FAT32.

There is a much better way to do multiple boots on one SD card with Bookworm. See autoboot.txt in https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html. In the first boot partition create a file autoboot.txt with [all] (newline) boot_partition=2 if you want to boot to partition 2 as your preferred OS. If you need to boot to partition 1, sudo reboot 1. Or the other way around.
pi@R15:~ $ lsblk -o NAME,MAJ:MIN,SIZE,TYPE,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT
NAME        MAJ:MIN  SIZE TYPE FSTYPE LABEL    MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0   29.7G disk                 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    512M part vfat   bw       /media/pi/bw
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    512M part vfat   be       /boot
├─mmcblk0p3 179:3    512M part                 
├─mmcblk0p4 179:4      1K part                 
├─mmcblk0p5 179:5     10G part ext4   Bookworm /media/pi/Bookworm
├─mmcblk0p6 179:6     10G part ext4   Bullseye /
└─mmcblk0p7 179:7    8.2G part ext4   Test     /media/pi/Test



The led on the raspberry pi goes on and with any version of BerryBoot the rainbow screen appears but nothing is happening.

That's probably exactly the same thing as it does with no card in it, meaning whatever is on the card is just no good.
Note that the last version of BerryBoot I could find (the same one you downloaded from SourceForge) was released a the beginning of August 2021, but the Pi Zero 2W was not released until the end of October of that year.  Since it uses the Pi 3 SoC, BerryBoot might have firmware for it, but it is not really surprising that it does not work.
I think you will be wasting your time trying to get it to.

PINN has too many problems

From the sound of things, it could not possibly have more problems than BerryBoot, and at least PINN appears to be actively maintained.
Perhaps you are asking the wrong question, see the XY problem.
